# Android Java Reading a Text file from res/raw , file not found error

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to read a text file that is stored under *res/raw*. I cannot workout why the file will not open and read the contents to the textArea "`usersTextArea`". The system just outputs `System.out.println("file could not open");`. I don't think the file path is incorrect. Anyone know what could be causing the problem? Thanks.

```
public void readFile()
{        
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.users;

    try
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(path));

        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            String data = scan.next();
            usersTextArea.append(data);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        System.out.println("file could not open");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access raw resources like this:

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.users)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like:

```
public void readFile() {
    final InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.users);
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
    try {
        // read the file
    } finally {
        // don't forget to close the resources, once you are done with them
        scanner.close();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

provide Read/Write permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then you can read res/raw file